# brew Error: No available formula with the name "node@11"

Tags: node.js, npm, homebrew

I'm getting some errors with node v12.6 so I'm trying to downgrade to node@11.

Doing a `brew install node@11` gives me the title error, and I've not found many results in Google for how to proceed.

Full error:-

```
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/core).
==> New Formulae
wtfutil
==> Updated Formulae
glooctl           juju              k6                moarvm            moe               nqp               pulumi            rakudo            terraform         topgrade          xrootd

Error: No available formula with the name "node@11" 
==> Searching for a previously deleted formula (in the last month)...
Warning: homebrew/core is shallow clone. To get complete history run:
  git -C "$(brew --repo homebrew/core)" fetch --unshallow

Error: No previously deleted formula found.
==> Searching for similarly named formulae...
Error: No similarly named formulae found.
==> Searching taps...
==> Searching taps on GitHub...
Error: No formulae found in taps.
```

`brew search node` gives me the following, so it doesn't appear I have 11 installed already.

```
leafnode          libbitcoin-node   llnode            node ✔            node-build        node@10           node@8            node_exporter     nodebrew          nodeenv           nodenv
```

Comment: Have you tried to switch with [NVM](https://github.com/nvm-sh/nvm)? It's a great tool for developing with different node versions.

Comment: That's what I ended up doing - installing v.11with NVM was a piece of cake.

Comment: Happy to hear you got it working, I'll post my comment as an answer then.

Comment: Woops, sorry - beat you to it.  But thanks anyway!

Comment: No worries, as long as one of us did it :D

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I'm not sure what caused my error, but a way around this was to install `v11` with NVM, following the guide below:-

https://www.npmjs.com/package/nvm

To install NVM, and then node version 11, just do the following:

```
$ brew install nvm
$ nvm install 11
```

Answer (score -1):

```
**TERMINAL**
curl -o- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.38.0/install.sh | bash
or
wget -qO- https://raw.githubusercontent.com/nvm-sh/nvm/v0.38.0/install.sh | bash

export NVM_DIR="$([ -z "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME-}" ] && printf %s "${HOME}/.nvm" || printf %s "${XDG_CONFIG_HOME}/nvm")"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm
```